# Q: sorting a table of numbers in Lua

Tags: lua

I've looked around for a bit to find a solution to my problem but I haven't gotten anything that completely fixes it. Essentially the function does sort but it doesn't sort the numbers in the table just the numbers 1 through 10

```
local numbers = {18, 45, 90, 77, 65, 18, 3, 57, 81, 10}

local function selectionSort(t)--t is the table to be sorted
 
  local t = {18, 45, 90, 77, 65, 18, 3, 57, 81, 10}
  
  local tkeys = {}
for k in pairs(t) do table.insert(tkeys, k) end
table.sort(tkeys)
for _, k in ipairs(tkeys) do print(k, t[k]) end
     
     
  return t -- return the sorted table
end

list = selectionSort(list)
```

and this is what comes out

```
1   18
2   45
3   90
4   77
5   65
6   18
7   3
8   57
9   81
10  10
```

and what I want is

```
3   18
10  45
18  90
18  77
45  65
57  18
65  3
77  57
81  81
90  10
```

any solutions?

Comment: You need to provide the sorting logic `table.sort(tkeys, function(a,b) return t[a] < t[b] end)`

Comment: Sorry... i just saw what you wanted... i dont understand how is that sorted? how does `77` relate to `18`? I dont follow how your desired output is a sorted list of `{18, 45, 90, 77, 65, 18, 3, 57, 81, 10}`

Comment: "and what I want is" `3   18,  10  45,  18  90,  18  77`??  What's the correlation here;  it's less sorted than before?

Comment: what I want is the list printed in it's original order then have it print the list out sorted by smallest number to largest

Comment: oh i see what you mean now, the left row is "sorted" the right row is "original"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are taking the `key` from your input and you want the value.

you can change it to:

```
local list = {18, 45, 90, 77, 65, 18, 3, 57, 81, 10}

local function selectionSort(t)--t is the table to be sorted
  
  local tSorted = {}
  for _,v in pairs(t) do 
    table.insert(tSorted, v)    
  end
  
  table.sort(tSorted)
  
  for i=1,#t,1 do 
    print(tSorted[i], t[i]) 
  end
  
  return tSorted -- return the sorted table
end

list = selectionSort(numbers)
```

and you will get:

```
sorted  original
3       18
10      45
18      90
18      77
45      65
57      18
65      3
77      57
81      81
90      10
```

Comment: fixed a little mistake, hope you don't mind

Comment: @Piglet perfectly fine, totally missed that in the original code was returning the input